# Sql Select Distinct Row Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select distinct DP, RN and from the result select only results where another col in the table 'EDate' = value, then after this get the amount of rows. This is what I have so far but it doesn't work..

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS eCount 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM
         (SELECT DISTINCT
              DP, RN
          FROM 
              ECount 
          WHERE
              DType = 'STRUCT')
     WHERE
         Month(EDate) = '07')) AS rows
```

In case this is suggested I can't add the `EDate` to the `Select Distinct` as I don't want that to mess up my distinct selection.

example

```
DP      RN      Edate    
DP01    RN01    21/06/2017    
DP01    RN01    22/07/2017  
DP02    RN03    22/07/2017   yes 
DP02    RN03    22/07/2017    
DP01    RN04    22/07/2017   yes
DP02    RN05    22/07/2017   yes
DP03    RN06    22/07/2017   yes
```

result should = 4

Comment: would you please add some data example? I am trying to understand your question better

Comment: @Fmanin please see example

Comment: from where this: `DType = 'STRUCT'` is coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `WHERE Month(EDate) = '07'` in the outer query since `EDate` is not a part of the inner query.

Try it with a one derived table less:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DP, RN
    FROM ECount t0
    WHERE DType = 'STRUCT'
    AND Month(EDate) = 7
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM ECount t1
        WHERE t1.DP = t0.DP
        AND t1.RN = t0.RN
        AND t1.Month(EDate) <> 7
        AND t1.DType = 'STRUCT' -- Not sure about this condition
    )
) As rows
```

Comment: @ Zohar, please see my example. The issue i have with your suggestion is will pick up the DP01 RN01 22/07/2017 in my list but as it's not distinct in the table i don't want to pick it up, if that makes sense..

Comment: I've added a `not exists` condition to the derived table. Check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With Cte
As
(
    Select 
        DP,
        RN,
        EDate,
        Row_Number() Over(Partition By DP Order By RN Desc) As RowNum 
    From Example
    Where Month(EDate) = 07
)
Select 
    DP, 
    RN, 
    EDate
From Cte
Where RowNum = 1
Order By DP;
```

Comment: I just realised i made a mistake with my example i don't  mind if the row exists more than once i just want one occurence of this. However if there is more than 1 existence and its from a previous month then i want to exclude both.